# Xboxdrv "windows/super" key EV_KEY name

Tags: linux, keyboard, xbox360, pad

I want to map windows/super keyboard key in my xboxdrv config but KEY_SUPER or KEY_WINDOWS doesn't work. what is the EV_KEY name of the "super" key? (I mean key with windows logo on many keyboards)

Comment: Thanks for asking this, I was searching https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h for "super" but didn't think to search for "meta", and your question was at the top for a search on "linux key_super". The answer below suggesting `KEY_LEFTMETA` is spot on!

Answer (score 1):

Either `KEY_LEFTMETA` or `KEY_RIGHTMETA`.

You can find it out using evtest, for example:

```
$ evtest /dev/input/event1
```

Once you press the button you are looking for, you should see something like this:

```
Event: time 1477389229.423141, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 126 (KEY_RIGHTMETA), value 1
```